# taskSnaphot.getDownloadUrl() is not working. What to do for this?

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am uploading images to FirebaseStorage i have write this code but tasksnapshot.getDownloadUrl() is not working. What to do for this ?
Please tell, it would be great help.

My code is:

```
public void UploadImageFileToFirebaseStorage() {

    if (FilePathUri != null) {
        progressDialog.setTitle("Image is Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();
        StorageReference storageReference2nd = storageReference.child(Storage_Path + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + GetFileExtension(FilePathUri));
        storageReference2nd.putFile(FilePathUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        String TempImageName = ImageName.getText().toString().trim();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded Successfully ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
                        ImageUploadInfo imageUploadInfo = new ImageUploadInfo(TempImageName, taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        String ImageUploadId = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                        databaseReference.child(ImageUploadId).setValue(imageUploadInfo);
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(AddBanner.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.setTitle("Image is Uploading...");

                    }
                });
    }
    else {

        Toast.makeText(AddBanner.this, "Please Select Image or Add Image Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Please solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

//Define Variables.

```
private Uri filePath;
private final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 71;
```

//Firebase

```
FirebaseStorage storage;
StorageReference storageReference;
```

//In onCreate method.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        storageReference = storage.getReference();

    }
```

First of all check that your choose an Image from Gallery.
method to choose image.

```
private void chooseImage() {
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setType("image/*");
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}
```

//onActivityResult methode to get the image uri.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
          && data != null && data.getData() != null )
  {
    filePath = data.getData();
    try {
      Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
      imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

//Upload image method.

```
private void uploadImage() 
{ 
  if(filePath != null)
  {
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
    progressDialog.show();
 
    StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/"+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    ref.putFile(filePath)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
              @Override
              public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            })
            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
              @Override
              public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                        .getTotalByteCount());
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
              }
            });
  }
}
```

//Be sure to define those perrmission. in android

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You should first upload the image as these code by calling the choose chooseImage and then the uploadImage method

and show me the error in downloading you have.